# Can my empty TextInput value be sent to the DataProvider as empty string instead of converted to null?

Tags: react-admin

I'm using a `<TextInput>` in a `<SimpleForm>` and when I clear out the value at runtime, react-admin sets the property's value to `null` when it sends the values to the DataProvider. I would like to store empty strings instead of null. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: How do you clear the values at runtime?

Comment: @MiguelAraya with empty strings replacing null values

Comment: I was expecting some code, inside a FormDataConsumer?

Comment: @MiguelAraya The value is being cleared out by the user (e.g. by deleting the text in the textbox), not by calling code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use react-final-form `parse` prop for that (see https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldProps#parse):

```
<TextInput
    source="author.name"
    parse={value => value}
/>
```

The default will convert empty string to `undefined` (see https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/faq#why-does-final-form-set-my--field-value-to-undefined) and react-admin convert those undefined values to null.

Answer (score 1):

Current version of `react-admin` allows you to change this behavior with `sanitizeEmptyValues` prop:

```js
export const PostEdit = (props) => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm sanitizeEmptyValues={false}>
            <TextInput source="title" />
            <JsonInput source="body" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

More details in official docs: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#setting-empty-values-to-null

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `initialValue=""` prop into it, like

```
<TextInput initialValue="" />
```

Which will override it into an empty string when it is `null` or `undefined`

Comment: That accomplishes something different